# Using RestClient instead of curl -- how do I do that?

Tags: ruby, curl, rest-client

I am trying to use RestClient to do the following which is currently in Curl:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST --data '{"contacts" : [1111],"text" : "Testing"}' https://api.sendhub.com/v1/messages/?username=NUMBER\&api_key=APIKEY
```

I don't see in the docs for RestClient how to perform the equivalent as "--data" above as well as passing -H (Header) information.

I tried the following:

```
url = "https://api.sendhub.com/v1/messages/?username=#{NUMBER}\&api_key=#{APIKEY}"
smspacket = "{'contacts':[#{contact_id}], 'text' : ' #{text} ' }"

RestClient.post url , smspacket, :content_type => 'application/json'
```

But this give me a **Bad Request** error.

Comment: Are you sure the url you created is correct? Meaning does the value replaced by NUMBER and APIKEY equal what you expect?

Comment: Yeah the number is right, I figured it out...hardcoding the JSON formatting was the error.

Comment: One possibility is that the RestClient adds some headers that your API does not accept. Looking the source code, it does seem to add some default headers: `{:accept => '*/*; q=0.5, application/xml', :accept_encoding => 'gzip, deflate'}`. Do you need to use this library? There are many other libraries out there you can use to make http requests.

Comment: I liked RestClient for some reason in the past...but I think I figured it out....I actually needed to use I believe a .to_json method and not use the format above and they were able to process it.

Answer (score 1):

I presume this is probably very late, but for the record and since I was hanging around with my own question.

Your problem weren't really with the use or not of the `:to_json` method, since it will output a string anyway. The body request has to be a string.
According to http://json.org strings in json have to be defined with `"` and not with `'`, even if in javascript we mostly used to write json this way. Same if you use no quote at all for keys.

This is probably why you received a bad request.

```
pry(main)> {"test": "test"}.to_json
"{\"test\":\"test\"}"
pry(main)> JSON.parse(RestClient.post('http://httpbin.org/post', "{'test': 'test'}", {content_type: :json, accept: :json}).body)["json"]
nil
pry(main)> JSON.parse(RestClient.post('http://httpbin.org/post', '{test: "test"}', {content_type: :json, accept: :json}).body)["json"]
nil
pry(main)> JSON.parse(RestClient.post('http://httpbin.org/post', '{"test": "test"}', {content_type: :json, accept: :json}).body)["json"]
{"test"=>"test"}
```